# What is this Strange Behavior of the Optimal Guess in Hi Lo?

Tags: expected-value, game-theory

I started playing the simplest hi/lo game I could think of with my 3 year old with the goal of having him practice his numbers.

Me: I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10

My son: 4

Me: higher

My son: 7

Me: lower

My son: 6

Me: right

Now as I'm sitting there I thought about trying to introduce him to the optimal strategy of always picking the number in the middle.  Arming myself against the inevitable "why?", I got to thinking: is this always the best?  For numbers of the form $2^k-1$ this is the right strategy, but for others it may not be. I decided to write a script to compute it.

"Optimal" in my script was computed based on what my son should guess if I say "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and N" and he wanted to have the lowest number of expected guesses. For 10, the answer turned out NOT to be 5 or 6, but rather 4 or 7. I found this quite peculiar.

To visualize this for a whole bunch of numbers, I created this image where the row in the image represents N, and the red pixels indicate the which guesses are optimal for that N.  The image is generated based on N from 1 to 256.

[image: hilograph256.bmp]

What's going on here? Is there deeper mathematics going on other than "yeah, that's what the math works out to be". There seems to be a deeper pattern going on and I would enjoy it if people smarter than myself had a satisfying answer to give.

For anyone interested in the code (I didn't write it with readability in mind), I put the hilo function [here](https://github.com/frankbryce/linux_scripts/blob/master/bin/hilo.py) and the hilograph function [here](https://github.com/frankbryce/linux_scripts/blob/master/bin/hilograph.py).

EDIT:

The accepted answer from Frosty is correct, and the gaps were due to floating point errors in the python code. I wanted to post the picture here for posterity.

[image: hilograph256fixed.bmp]

There is still some interesting math going on. For example: it's always an optimal guess to pick some $2^k$ for some k, no matter which N you choose :). At least something cool still came from this.

You can see the edited code from the same links above, but you'll have to look at the revision history to see the original code that produced the pretty, but incorrect, version of the picture.

Comment: If I’m meant to guess a number from $1$ to $N$, how is that number actually generated? Uniformly at random? And could you describe the optimality criterion more explicitly?

Comment: The number is generated randomly in the range, and optimal means the guess which minimizes the number of guesses. So for N=3 the expected number of guesses that's optimal is 5/3 (by picking 2).

Comment: **minimizes the expected number of guesses

Comment: Also, I meant uniformly random.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps you could edit the question to make it clearer, since the first time you mention "optimal" you say it is picking the middle number, but that’s not really what you want. Uniform randomness would be good to know in the question too.

Comment: Will do in the morning. Currently in bed about to sleep

Comment: I don’t quite see how your code calculates the best guess that minimises the expected number of guesses though... It would be nice if you had an informal description of how you calculated this too.

Comment: Sure, take your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct in a theoretical sense, but it runs into issues when dealing with very precise floating point comparisons.

If you instead store the total number of guesses required for your strategy to work for every possible case (instead of computing the average case), you can use integers and avoid this issue.

All that's required for this method is changing line 13 to output (3,[1,2]), line 14 to be something large (try n*n), and change line 22 to be `e=le+re+n`.

Once those changes have been made, the valid initial guesses become a continuous range with no gaps.

Comment: You are right, it was a floating point error.  I'm still struggling to understand why this suggestion works though.  I coded it and it produces the picture you say it does (except the initial minE value has to be at least n cubed I think). The thing I'm hung up on is that `le` and `re` aren't equally likely to happen and the lack of taking this into account in the math doesn't let me close the conceptual circle here.

Comment: Another way to deal with the floating-point issues is to apply a tolerance in your comparisons. I would also do multiple passes over the range of initial guesses so that you know the absolute minimum expected number of guesses before you put anything into minG. With these changes I get a continuous range of integers in minG.

Answer (score 1):

In your $1$ to $10$ example, if you guess $4$ or $7$ (aside from when you are right the first time) the remaining numbers are split $3+6$ instead of $4+5$ when you guess $5$ or $6$.  We can make a table with $N$ the upper limit of the number, $E(N)$ being the expected number of guesses, $G$ being the number to guess next.  The key is that $E(N)=1+\min_G((G-1)E(G-1))+(N-G)E(N-G))/N)$ because by guessing $G$ you split the range into $(G-1),1,(N-G)$ and have used one guess.
$$\begin {array} {r |r| r}N&E(N)&G\\ \hline 1&1&1\\
2&3/2&1\\3&5/3&2\\4&2&2\\5&11/5&3\\6&7/3&3\end {array}$$
Now for $N=10$ we can compute the the expectation for guessing $4$ is $1+(3\cdot (5/3)+6\cdot (7/3))/10=29/10=2.9$ while the expectation for guessing $5$ is $1+(4\cdot 2+5\cdot (11/5))/10=29/10=2.9$  I find it does not matter which you guess from an expected number of guesses point of view.

Comment: This math is wrong. The correct value of E(4) is 2. Your formula is thrown off by the fact that you're dividing by N-1, when you should divide by N, to account for the probability that you guess right on the first try.

Comment: @Frosty:  you are right.  Fixed.  It turns out for $N=10$ you can guess any number $3-6$ with equal expectation.

Comment: 4-7, but yeah. See my answer; I believe the bug arises from floating point comparisons.